# SI Units power messing up fraction display

Tags: siunitx, fractions, units

I realized that when I put the power on the unit, the m/s^2 is displayed inline instead of in a `\frac` format.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        \SI[per-mode=fraction]{9.81}{\meter\per\second}
    \end{equation*}
    \begin{equation*}
        \SI[per-mode=fraction]{9.81}{\meter\per\second^2}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: current output]

Is there a way to display m/s^2 in a `\frac` format?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, in the `siunitx` package they want you to type units in a similar way you would express those same units orally. For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        %\SI[per-mode=fraction]{9.81}{\meter\per\second}
        \SI[per-mode=fraction]{9.81}{\meter\per\second\squared}
        \quad
        \SI[per-mode=fraction]{9.81}{\meter\per\square\second}
    \end{equation*}
    \begin{equation*}
        \SI[per-mode=fraction]{9.81}{\meter\per\second^2}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps add that `\meter\per\second^2` is treated as 'literal' input: there's no attempt to parse it, rather `siunitx` simply typesets the input in math mode.